# Erro ao editar registro mais de uma vez com EntityFramework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, winforms

Ao editar um registro e salvar pela primeira vez o entityframework realiza a atualização com sucesso, porém quando clico novamente em editar e salvo o registro me deparo com o seguinte erro:

> Erro ao salvar registro: Attaching an entity of type
>   'Projeto.WebERP.EntityFramework.Entities.Cadastros.Localidade.Cidade'
>   failed because another entity of the same type already has the same
>   primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or
>   setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any
>   entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because
>   some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key
>   values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state
>   to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to
>   'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Oque estou fazendo de errado?

**RepositorioBase**

```
public abstract class RepositorioBase<TEntity> : IRepositorioCRUD<TEntity>, IRepositioSQL<TEntity>
    where TEntity : EntityBase
{
    public RepositorioBase()
    {
        _context = new ProjetoContext();
    }

    ProjetoContext _context;

    public long GetNextHandle()
    {
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<TEntity>();
        var tabela = instance.GetType().Name.ToUpper();
        var handle = _context.Database.SqlQuery<long>("SELECT (COALESCE(MAX(HANDLE),0) + 1) HANDLE FROM " + tabela).ToArray();
        return Convert.ToInt64(handle[0]);            
    }

    public long Inserir(TEntity entity)
    {
        try
        {
            entity.Handle = GetNextHandle();
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
            _context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added;

            var erros = _context.GetValidationErrors();
            if (erros.Count() > 0)
            {
                string stringErro = string.Empty;
                foreach (var erro in erros)
                    foreach (var er in erro.ValidationErrors)
                        stringErro += string.Format(er.ErrorMessage.ToString() + " {0}", Environment.NewLine);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringErro))
                    throw new Exception(stringErro);
            }
            return _context.SaveChanges();

        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            throw new Exception(erro.Message);
        }
    }

    public virtual bool Atualizar(TEntity entity)
    {
        try 
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
            _context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;

            var erros = _context.GetValidationErrors();
            if (erros.Count() > 0)
            {
                string stringErro = string.Empty;
                foreach (var erro in erros)
                    foreach (var er in erro.ValidationErrors)
                        stringErro += string.Format(er.ErrorMessage.ToString() + " {0}", Environment.NewLine);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringErro))
                    throw new Exception(stringErro);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return true;                
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            throw new Exception(erro.Message);
        }
    }

    public bool Deletar(TEntity entity)
    {
        try
        {


            _context.Set<TEntity>().Attach(entity);
            _context.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;

            var erros = _context.GetValidationErrors();
            if (erros.Count() > 0)
            {
                string stringErro = string.Empty;
                foreach (var erro in erros)
                    foreach (var er in erro.ValidationErrors)
                        stringErro += string.Format(er.ErrorMessage.ToString() + " {0}", Environment.NewLine);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringErro))
                    throw new Exception(stringErro);
            }
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return true;                
        }
        catch (Exception erro)
        {
            throw new Exception(erro.Message);
        }
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
    }

    public IQueryable<TEntity> Find(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().Where(where).AsQueryable();
    }

    public TEntity GetByHandle(long handle)
    {
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Handle == handle);
    }

    public IQueryable<TResult> FindSelect<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> select, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> where)
    {            
        return _context.Set<TEntity>().AsNoTracking().Where(where).Select(select).AsQueryable<TResult>();
    }
}
```

**Formulário de Cadastro de Cidade**

```
public partial class FormularioCidade : FormularioBase
{
    public FormularioCidade()
    {
        InitializeComponent();            
    }

    RepositorioBase<Pais> _RepositorioPais = new RepositorioPais();
    RepositorioBase<Estado> _RepositorioEstado = new RepositorioEstado();
    RepositorioBase<Cidade> _RepositorioCidade = new RepositorioCidade();

    public override void LoadFormulario()
    {
        bsGrid.DataSource = ObterRegistrosParaGrid(x => x.Handle > 0).ToList();
    }

    public override void BotaoNovo()
    {
        bsCidade.AddNew();

        PopularBSPais();
    }

    public override void BotaoEditar()
    {
        PopularBSPais();

        PosicionarPais();
        PosicionarEstado();
    }

    private IQueryable<object> ObterRegistrosParaGrid(Expression<Func<Cidade, bool>> where)
    {
        return _RepositorioCidade.FindSelect(x => new
        {
            Handle = x.Handle,
            Descricao = x.Descricao,
            Sigla = x.Sigla,
            Estado = x.Estado,
            EstadoHandle = x.Estado.Handle,
            EstadoDescricao = x.Estado.Descricao,
            Pais = x.Estado.Pais,
            PaisHandle = x.Estado.Pais.Handle,
            PaisDescricao = x.Estado.Pais.Descricao,
            DataCadastro = x.DataCadastro,
            DataAlteracao = x.DataAlteracao
        }, where).AsQueryable();
    }

    public override void BotaoSalvar()
    {
        if (State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            Cidade currentCidade = (bsCidade.Current as Cidade);
            Pais currentPais = (bsCidade.Current as Pais);
            Estado currentEstado = (bsCidade.Current as Estado);

            Cidade cidade = new Cidade();
            cidade.Handle = _RepositorioCidade.GetNextHandle();
            cidade.Descricao = currentCidade.Descricao;
            cidade.Sigla = currentCidade.Sigla;
            cidade.Estado = currentEstado;
            cidade.EstadoHandle = currentEstado.Handle;
            cidade.Estado.Pais = currentPais;
            cidade.Estado.PaisHandle = currentPais.Handle;
            cidade.DataAlteracao = null;
            cidade.DataCadastro = DateTime.Now;

            _RepositorioCidade.Inserir(cidade);

            var newCidade = ObterRegistrosParaGrid(x => x.Handle == cidade.Handle).FirstOrDefault();

            bsGrid.Add(newCidade);


        }
        else if (State == EntityState.Modified)
        {
            Cidade currentCidade = (bsCidade.Current as Cidade);
            Pais currentPais = (bsPais.Current as Pais);
            Estado currentEstado = (bsEstado.Current as Estado);

            Cidade cidade = new Cidade();
            cidade.Handle = currentCidade.Handle;
            cidade.Descricao = currentCidade.Descricao;
            cidade.Sigla = currentCidade.Sigla;
            cidade.Estado = currentEstado;
            cidade.EstadoHandle = currentEstado.Handle;
            cidade.Estado.Pais = currentPais;
            cidade.Estado.PaisHandle = currentPais.Handle;
            cidade.DataAlteracao = DateTime.Now;
            cidade.DataCadastro = currentCidade.DataCadastro;

            _RepositorioCidade.Atualizar(cidade);


            var newCidade = ObterRegistrosParaGrid(x => x.Handle == cidade.Handle).FirstOrDefault();

            var indice = bsGrid.IndexOf(bsGrid.Current);
            bsGrid.RemoveAt(indice);
            bsGrid.Insert(indice, newCidade);
            bsGrid.Position = indice;
        }
    }

    public override void BotaoCancelar()
    {
        PopularCamposCadastro();
    }

    public override void BotaoExcluir()
    {
        Cidade cidade = (bsCidade.Current as Cidade);

        _RepositorioCidade.Deletar(cidade);

        var indice = bsGrid.IndexOf(bsGrid.Current);
        bsGrid.RemoveAt(indice);
    }

    public override void BotaoPesquisar()
    {

    }

    private void bsPais_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        long handlePais = (bsPais.Current as Pais).Handle;
        PopularBSEstado(handlePais);
    }

    private void bsGrid_CurrentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopularCamposCadastro();

        lblTotalRegistros.Text = string.Format("Registro {0} de {1}", bsGrid.IndexOf(bsGrid.Current) + 1, bsGrid.Count);
    }

    private void PopularCamposCadastro()
    {
        if (bsGrid.Current != null)
        {
            Cidade cidade = (bsGrid.Current as object).ToEntity<Cidade>();
            Pais pais = (bsGrid.Current as dynamic).Pais;
            Estado estado = (bsGrid.Current as dynamic).Estado;

            bsCidade.DataSource = cidade;
            bsPais.DataSource = pais;
            bsEstado.DataSource = estado;
        }
    }

    private void PopularBSPais()
    {
        bsPais.DataSource = _RepositorioPais.GetAll().ToList();
    }

    private void PopularBSEstado(long handlePais)
    {
        if (handlePais > 0)
        {
            bsEstado.DataSource = _RepositorioEstado.Find(x => x.PaisHandle == handlePais).ToList();
        }
    }

    private void PosicionarPais()
    {
        if (bsGrid.Current != null)
        {
            long handlePais = (bsGrid.Current as dynamic).PaisHandle;                
            bsPais.Position = (bsPais.IndexOf((bsPais.List as List<Pais>).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Handle == handlePais)));

        }
    }

    private void PosicionarEstado()
    {
        if (bsGrid.Current != null)
        {
            long handleEstado = (bsGrid.Current as dynamic).EstadoHandle;
            bsEstado.Position = (bsEstado.IndexOf((bsEstado.List as List<Estado>).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Handle == handleEstado)));
        }
    }

}
```

**Classe Cidade**

```
[Serializable]
public class Cidade : EntityBase
{
    public override long Handle { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public string Sigla { get; set; }
    public long EstadoHandle { get; set; }
    public virtual Estado Estado { get; set; }        
    public override DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }
    public override DateTime? DataAlteracao { get; set; }
}
```

**Fluent API Classe Cidade**

```
public class CidadeMap : EntityBaseTypeConfiguration<Cidade>
{
    public override void ConfigureTableName()
    {
        ToTable("CIDADE");
    }

    public override void ConfigurePrimaryKey()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Handle)
            .Property(x => x.Handle).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }

    public override void ConfigureForeingKeys()
    {
        HasRequired(p => p.Estado)
            .WithMany(p => p.Cidades)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.EstadoHandle);
    }

    public override void ConfigureProperties()
    {
        Property(p => p.EstadoHandle)
            .HasColumnName("ESTADOHANDLE")
            .IsRequired();            

        Property(p => p.Descricao)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(150)
            .HasColumnName("DESCRICAO");

        Property(p => p.Sigla)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(3)
            .HasColumnName("SIGLA");
    }

    public override void ConfigureHasMany()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O contexto do Entity Framework guarda (cache) as entidades que você manipulou previamente. Quando você tenta inserir/alterar uma entidade que já existe, ele dá esse erro, porque ela está em memória já. O correto é obter a entidade **diretamente** do contexto, através do método `Find` e atualizar as informações desta entidade diretamente ao invés de tentar inserir uma nova.

```
public virtual bool Atualizar(TEntity entity)
{
    try 
    {
        if(_context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
          // Obtém a entidade do contexto usando a chave primária da entidade que contém os dados atualizados.
          // Esta entidade está sendo rastreada pelo contexto e vai persistir as alterações feitas nela.
          var obj = _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(entity.Id);

          if (obj != null)
          {
             // Atualiza a entidade que está sendo rastreada pelo contexto com as informações contidas na entidade que você passou para este método.
             _context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(obj);
          }
        }

        var erros = _context.GetValidationErrors();
        if (erros.Count() > 0)
        {
            string stringErro = string.Empty;
            foreach (var erro in erros)
                foreach (var er in erro.ValidationErrors)
                    stringErro += string.Format(er.ErrorMessage.ToString() + " {0}", Environment.NewLine);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringErro))
                throw new Exception(stringErro);
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return true;                
    }
    catch (Exception erro)
    {
        throw new Exception(erro.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Erro continua amigo.

Comment: Tente remover completamente esta linha, veja se o erro persiste.

Comment: qual linha você se refere ?

Comment: Atualizei minha resposta

Comment: deu certo amigo, poderia me explicar melhor essa forma de atualizar o registro ?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta com mais informações.